# What is right and left of element in CSS

Tags: html, css, position

What is right and left of elements in CSS.
When I tried to move element left: 150px . It moves right and vice versa.

Comment: give your code.. it really helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`left`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) is the distance from the left edge; [`right`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) is the distance from the right edge.

For instance, if I set `left: 10px`, it will move the element 10px **away from** the left edge of the element.

If you want to move **to the left**, you can use negative values, e.g. `left: -10px`.

The same applies to the `top` and `bottom` properties.

---

> W3Schools puts it this way:
>
> Sets the left edge of the image [distance] to the right of the left edge of its containing element

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a position of element (relative/absolute/fixed/ect) the left and right tags all you to align to and **offset**:
ex. (left:0px;) will align to the left by 0 px or (left:15px;) will align to the left and offset by 15px.. 
(offset meaning, it pushes from the left 15px out)

Relative positioning you must specify a value- won't take %

absolute position is in relation to it's parents positioning, so you can use % with absolute positioning and left/right:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left;` and `float: right;` to achieve basic positioning. If you are looking for more advanced positioning could you please post your code so that we can see what you are trying to do! :)